# List View custom Adapter doesn't work, when I open the Activity nothing is displayed

Tags: android, listview, layout

This is my custom Adapter for a doctor. I also use a custom layout for the ListView, but just contains 5 TextViews

```
public class DoctorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Doctor> {
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<Doctor> doctors;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public DoctorAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Doctor> doctors,LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context=context;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.doctors=doctors;
        this.layoutInflater=layoutInflater;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(resource,parent,false);
        Doctor doctor=doctors.get(position);
        if(doctor!=null){

            TextView tvNume=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrNume);
            tvNume.setText(doctor.getNume());

            TextView tvPrenume=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrPrenume);
            tvPrenume.setText(doctor.getPrenume());

            TextView tvData=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrBirth);
            tvData.setText(doctor.getBirthday().toString());
//            TextView tvProfesie=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrProfession);
//            tvProfesie.setText(doctor.getProfesie());
            TextView tvEmail=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrEmail);
            tvEmail.setText(doctor.getEmail());

            TextView tvTelefon=view.findViewById(R.id.seeDrTelefon);
            tvTelefon.setText(doctor.getTelefon());
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is how I use it in my Activity:

```
 private ListView lvDocs;
    private ArrayList<Doctor> doctors;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_doctors);
        doctors=(ArrayList<Doctor>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("DOCTORS");
        lvDocs=findViewById(R.id.lvDocs);
        DoctorAdapter adapter=new DoctorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.elemlistview,
                    doctors,getLayoutInflater());
        lvDocs.setAdapter(adapter);
        
    }
```

Is there a problem if I use an ArrayList or a custom layout for the elements in the listView?

Comment: Change `super(context, resource);` to `super(context, resource, doctors);`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you very much